# chmod only certain mime-types

Tags: 14.04, permissions, chmod, mime-type

I'm using `file --mime-type *` to find the mime-types of all files in a selected directory.

Many of these files should not be executable and are `.conf` or their type is `text/plain`. Is there a combination of the `find` command that can change all non-executable mime-types back to `644` instead of `755`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like that:

```
file -F' ' --mime-type * | awk '$2 ~ /text\/plain/{print $1}' | xargs chmod 644
```

This changes all permissions to 644 if a file has the mime-type `text/plain`. Just replace the part in the `awk` body to whatever mime-type you wish. See `/etc/mime.types` for all available ones.

**Explanation:**

- The `-F' '` flag causes file to use a space as separator between the filename and the result. It's easier for the later `awk` statement
- The `awk` part prints only the name of the file if the second field (`$2`) of the output contains `text/plain`.
- `xargs` calls `chmod 644` on every item

Comment: If some of your files have non-default permissions (e.g., `600` or `700` for no access except for yourself, or `666` or `777` for general write access), and you want to preserve those read and write permissions, use `chmod -x`, which will turn off all the `x` (execute) bits and leave the rest alone.

Comment: Worked perfect! I did use what @G-Man suggested to ensure special permissions on certain files were not touched.

Comment: This will fail if any relevant filenames contain space. As long as we’re looking at a single directory – specifically, the current directory – (using `*`), and not looking at a directory tree (using `**` or `find`), it might be better to specify `-F/` on both `file` and `awk`. (Newline will still be a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Below, the `file --mime-type` command used in a python script. It changes the permissions of the file types(s) you define to the 'new_permissions', in a given directory (recursively).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os

directory = '/path/to/files'
m_subject = ('text/plain', 'another_mimetype')
new_permissions = '644'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        check_mtype = 'file --mime-type '+'"'+root+'/'+file+'"'
        mtype = subprocess.check_output(
            ['/bin/bash', '-c', check_mtype]).decode('utf-8').strip().split(' ')[-1]
        if mtype in m_subject:
            set_permissions = 'chmod '+str(new_permissions)+' '+root+'/'+file
            subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', set_permissions])
            print('permission set to '+new_permissions+' '+root+'/'+file)
```

Copy the script into an empty file, in the head section of the script, set the directory, the mime-types to change and the new permissions, save it as `change_types.py`.

Run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/change_types.py
```

Comment: Hmmm. I believe this will fail if any relevant filenames contain double quote (`"`).

Comment: @G-Man I honestly *never ever* ran into a file name with a '"'. Single once I believe.